# checking entire database during new post

Tags: php, database

i have customized cms built in PHP. my website have more than 2,00,000 posts. when i publish a new posts, it take too many time to publish a single posts.

When i publish new post, it is checking entire data base to find if the url is exist in the database. if it exist then it shows an error.

I want to know, is this necessary to check entire database to check, if the url exist already.

Because it is checking entire database before publishing, it takes lot of time and server goes down.

Comment: 1) depends on what the urls look like 2) create an index 3' if it really is searching through the entire **database** that would be pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the database to see if the URL is unique, simply force it to be unique by appending the ID of the new record to the URL string that you are saving and configure your website to work like that. For example, instead of you URL looking like:

```
mywebsite.com/post/test-post
```

Use something like

```
mywebsite.com/post/test-post/100
```

Where the 100 value is the ID of the post, which is a unique Primary Key

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a URL that is generated from the subject line of a post (which I suppose is what you're doing here, your question is a bit vague), then create a table that contains hashes of every URL and search for the hash. That's a quick binary search. You'll need to watch out for hash collisions, so you should store the string in full as well.